# IE8 jQuery is shortening dropdown list width size

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

All,
I've got the following url:
http://tinyurl.com/7fsbuhz

If you click on the Event Type you can't see all of the options because IE8 is shortening the width of the drop down list. I'm using a custom theme for this and it applies some CSS from jQuery and I'm ont sure why it would shorten the width. Can anyone help why it would shorten the width of the field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try using my plugin [Ideal Forms](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) and forget about headaches with custom forms once and for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there is a well documented bug with IE8 and selects not making the options wider than the initial list.

http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/

This should help you

Also, I can't even get your dropdown to work at all in Firefox 13